# Lookup on the basis of embedded documrnt

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I have a collection called assignmentTbl one record is stored as

```
    {
       _id : "6956GSVKU6535799",
       Type : "Project Abc",
       ...
       ...
       "TaskDetails"
        [
          { 
            "TaskId":"5759",
            "StudentId": ObjectId("5ab8845cff24ae1204000858"),
            ...
          },
          {
            "TaskId":"5659",
            "StudentId":  ObjectId("5ab8d7b1ff24ae1204000867"),
            ...
          }
          ...
        ]
    }
```

In studentTbl the data is like

```
   {
     "_id": ObjectId("5ab8d7b1ff24ae1204000867"),
     "profilePicture": "",
     "registration_temp_perm_no": "MGL-015",
     "admission_date": ISODate("2018-03-25T22:00:00.0Z"),
     "first_name": "Abrar",
     "middle_name": "",
     "last_name": "Khajwal",
     ...
   }
   ...
   ...
```

I want to write a query which will fetch data from assignment table and some student info (first_name and last_name) from studentTbl. Note that all the other fields from studentTbl are not required. I am not able to perform lookup aggregation on the basis of embedded document. Please help !!!

I have tried the below lines of code and it is returning empty.

```
public function fetchAllAllotments() 
{
    $pipeline = array(
        array(
            '$lookup' => array(
                'from' => 'studentTbl',
                'localField' => '_id',
                'foreignField' => 'TaskDetails.StudentId',
                'as' => 'StudentsDetails'
            )
        ), 

        array('$match' => array('id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->id)))
    );

    try
     {
        $cursor = $this->collection->aggregate($pipeline);
     } 
     catch (Exception $e) {

     }

   return $cursor->toArray();
}
```

Comment: You probably need to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) `TaskDetails` first because it is an array not an object.

Comment: Put `$unwind` stage before `$lookup`

Comment: can you please show me as it is very difficult to write mongo query myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `$unwind` first and then you can apply `$lookup` stage... and also your `localField` should be `TaskDetails.StudentId` and `foreignField` should be `_id`

```
public function fetchAllAllotments() 
{
    $pipeline = array(
        array('$match' => array('id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->id))),
        array('$unwind'=>'$TaskDetails'),
        array(
            '$lookup' => array(
                'from' => 'studentTbl',
                'localField' => 'TaskDetails.StudentId',
                'foreignField' => '_id',
                'as' => 'StudentsDetails'
            )
        )
    );

    try
     {
        $cursor = $this->collection->aggregate($pipeline);
     } 
     catch (Exception $e) {

     }

   return $cursor->toArray();
}
```

Comment: it returns empty array

Comment: @NidaAmin your localField and foreignField was incorrectly mentioned...

Comment: extremely sorry it still returns empty array

Comment: @NidaAmin `array('$match' => array('id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->id)))` when I remove this then the query works for me.

Comment: i need to fetch specific record from assignmentTbl (based on _id) then perform lookup in order to get some fields from studentTbl

Comment: @NidaAmin can you show me the screen shot of database

Comment: i will be back to u on this question